# How to strech / repeat a small png image according to the screen size in cocos2d-js?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am trying to strech/scale/repeat a small image based on the screen size, but I couldnot find a proper solution. Could someone help?

```
dmm.director = cc.director;
dmm.origin =  dmm.director.getVisibleOrigin();
dmm.size =  dmm.director.getVisibleSize();
dmm.midpoint = cc.p(
  dmm.origin.x + dmm.size.width * 0.5,
  dmm.origin.y + dmm.size.height * 0.5
);

this.bg_sprite = new cc.Sprite('#bg.png');
this.bg_sprite.setPosition(cc.p(dmm.midpoint.x,
  origin.y + size.height * 0.65));
this.addChild(this.bg_sprite);
```